# Python regular expressions - find character match with different word lengths

Tags: python, regex

I've been learning about regular expressions in Python and know that to find all words with only the characters [a, e, f, g, h, i, n] I can use the following:

```
t = [w for w in words if re.search('^[aefghin]$', w)]
```

And to find only 7 letter words with those characters I can use:

```
t = [w for w in words if re.search('^[aefghin]{7}$', w)]
```

However, how can I search for all words including these characters that have a length of *up to* 7 using regular expressions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern that match any combination of `[aefghin]` letters with length 1 to 7 (read more about [Limiting Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)):

```
[aefghin]{1,7}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RZvpcFlHj-ow8d_b)

Comment: This is obviously wrong, it will match strings that are longer than 7 characters.

Comment: Don't you need the ^ and the $ at the very beginning and end?

Comment: @Ben sorry its the OP's edit! i think he missed that! like me! :)

Comment: @Kasra I see! Still, the + means you can have 1 or more chars, up to 7 times - i.e. an unlimited length, as pointed out by vermillon

Comment: @Ben oops yeah! a foolish mistake! thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can use `'^[aefghin]{,7}$'`. or `{1,7}` if you want to exclude empty strings.

The syntax is `{minimum_number, maximum_number}`, but if you omit `minimum_number` it means "anything lesser than or equal to maximum_number (including 0)" and if you omit `maximum_number` it means "anything greater than or equal to minimum_number".

Comment: Same problem as my comment above. This is returning an empty list although I know for a fact that there are words that should be returned.

Comment: For instance? Can you give some examples of strings you'd expect to match but don't? I've tried it and it definitely works.